# Angular Template driven form, button enable and disabled with Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

We have created Template driven form in angular, I have used button disable in form, when my form is not valid then button should be disabled and if form is valid then button should be enabled. The button remains disabled when I enter the data in input fields and select the value   from Engine Number or Chassis Number dropdown. kindly Suggest me what I should do.

component.html

```html
<div class="motor-policy-container">
  <form 
    #motorForm="ngForm" 
    (ngSubmit)="registerMotorPolicy(motorForm.value, motorForm.valid)"
  >
    <label>Policy</label>
    <div>
      <input 
        class="input-box" 
        name="policy_number" 
        #motorpolicy_number="ngModel" 
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" 
        maxlength="20" 
        type="number" 
        placeholder="Enter policy number" 
        ngModel required
      />
    </div>
    <small 
      class="validation-error" 
      [hidden]="motorpolicy_number.valid || (motorpolicy_number.pristine && !motorForm.submitted)"
    >
      Policy number required.
    </small>
    <br>
    <select 
      id="motorDropdown" 
      name="motorNumber" 
      (change)="setValue($event.target.value)" 
      class="select-policy select-policy-dropdown"
    >
      <option value="vehicleNumber">Vehicle Registration Number</option>
      <option value="engineNumber">Engine Number</option>
      <option value="chassisNumber">Chassis Number</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input 
        class="input-box" 
        (input)="setMotorValue()" 
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" 
        id="vehicleNumber" 
        name="vehicleNumber" 
        placeholder="Vehicle Registration Number" 
        maxlength="20" 
        type="text" 
        ngModel required 
      />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="terms-container">
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="checkbox-1-3" 
        name="motor-terms" 
        #motor_terms="ngModel"  
        class="regular-checkbox" 
        ngModel required
      />
      <label for="checkbox-1-3"></label>
      <span>I have read the <a href="#" class="condition">Terms and Conditions</a> and agree to abide by the same.</span> 
      <br/>
      <small 
        class="validation-error" 
        [hidden]="motor_terms.valid || (motor_terms.pristine && !motorForm.submitted)"
      >
        Please accept terms and conditions
      </small>
    </div>
    <button 
      class="sbmt-btn" 
      type="submit" 
      [disabled]="!motorForm.valid || !motor_terms"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
setValue(val){
  this.motorType = val;
}

setMotorValue(val){
  this.motorValue = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For button you have `[disabled]="!motorForm.valid || !motor_terms"` and it seems to me that you actually want to check for `[disabled]="!motorForm.valid || !motor_terms.valid"`?

Comment: We want when we enter the  data in input field and select value from dropdown and click on checkbox after that our disable button should be enabled but my form button is not enabling we are not able to do that. kindly assist, what we have need to changes inside the form.

Comment: Have you tried to change check for disabled as I suggested? You do have [hidden]="motor_terms.valid... as a check for that element's visibility, so the !motor_terms.valid is the value you actually need.

Comment: as per your suggest, we have made changes the code, but we still have enter the data into the input fields, When we select the value from dropdown and select the checkbox, then the button of our form remains disabled.
You are requested to kindly share the sample by writing the code so that it is easy for us to understand.

Comment: Hm seems that it all works as it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-9gmggn

Comment: still button is disabled, When I enter data in the input fields and select Engine Number, or Chassis Number from the dropdown and select the checkbox, the button remains disabled.

kindly help me when the all condition is succeeded the button should be enable.

Comment: Can you recreate your code on stackblitz or paste the whole ts file of the component? There might be some var or method that affects the button besides the code that you pasted here, since the stackblitz example I linked works with the code you provided so far.

Comment: In component.ts section we have pasted the code for component.ts

Comment: Hm just a note, though, to be sure we understand each other: you need to insert the number under dropdown too to have the button enabled

Comment: We put a number in the first input Then selected engine number or chassis number from dropdown, then enter data in second input, even then the button remains disabled.